# AFNetworking How to send a string of post request?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

*AFNetworking How to send a string of post request?*

```
//restrinBASE64STRING is a NSString ,Program error
[manager POST:URLString parameters:restrinBASE64STRING success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: By default, AFNetworking assumes the request is a standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`. It can easily use a different request serializer in order to send JSON requests, too. The `parameters` should not be a simple string. It's not clear, though, in what format your server needs this base64 string. In what `Content-Type` is your server expecting the request to be? It would be very unusual for it to expect base64 string by itself.

Comment: If you really need to send a non-standard request, you wouldn't use `POST`, but rather you'd probably create your own `AFHTTPRequestOperation` object. But before we go down that road, it probably makes sense to confirm that your server is really expecting such a curious format for the `POST` request.

Comment: Solved the problem,thank you Very Much

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[restrinBASE64STRING dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
```